# JS Objects: dot notation inside bracket notation, lists inside bracket notation

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object like this:

```
var myob= {
title: 'Hey',
list: [3, 74, 25],
myObject: {
  myName: {
   first: "Joe",
   second: "Flynn"
}
}
```

I am trying to access the inner content via bracket notation.

```
myob["title"] //works fine, returns 'Hey'
myob["list[0]"] //Doesn't work, returns undefined
myob["myObject[objectTitle]"] //Doesn't work, returns undefined
```

Why doesn't this work? Is there a way I could do this, preferably still using the same content inside the brackets...?

Link to a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j24dxpao/

Comment: Why, because  it is looking for  `myob = {  "list[0]" : 123 }`, so no there is no way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: `myob['list'][0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each index has to be enclosed by it's own brackets.

To access those objects with those paths, use

```
myob["title"]
myob["list"][0] 
myob["myObject"]["objectTitle"]
```

Answer (score 4):

For these kind of string-based nested object access, you might wanna use a library like [lodash's get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) or equivalent, as it is not natively possible.

```
const _ = require("lodash")
const schoolEvent = {
    guests: [
        {name: "John", handsome: true},
        {name: "Ben", handsome: false}
    ]
}

_.get(schoolEvent, "guests[0].name") // "John"
```

Comment: Yes, but this is for an npm package and I don't want any dependencies

Comment: If this is the notation you dig, then implement your own get fn. Otherwise, stick with the native notation. As others have pointed out this is the only solution. The only downside is that you have to make sure that each time you go down a level, the key you're on exists. Otherwise, "undefined is not a function" will pop up

Answer (score 0):

```
var myob= {
title: 'Hey',
list: [3, 74, 25],
myObject: {
  myName: {
   first: "Joe",
   second: "Flynn"
}
}
```

each key can be accessed by

```
myob['title']
myob['list'][0]
myob['myObject']['objectTitle']
```